# Combine several queries in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

GraphQL API has the following queries available:

```
query getUsers {
  users {
    id
    name
  }
}

query getUserAge($id: String!) {
  user(id: $id) {
    age
  }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to combine both of these queries into one so we could get the users' names and ages in one go?

Comment: A related answer on github if it helps - https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/120

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap one into another [and combine params if necessary]:

```
query getUsersAndUserAge($id: String!) {
  users {
    id
    name
  }
  user(id: $id) {
    age
  }
}
```

You can use ready functions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727903/6124657

Comment: But we don't know the users' ids in advance. Is there a way to pass the `users { id }` to the `user(id: $id)`?

Comment: just ask `users` to contain `age`? ... **you're not asking about combining** but about possibility to use one query result as input for another? not possible [for now] ... as queries can be run in parallel ... list query is used on list view, item query on detail view (can use cached entries of list response), each has own requirements [and time]

Comment: Ah, ok. The issue is that for some reason the API is returning different values for `query getUsers { users { age } }` vs `user(id: "123") { age }` for the same user's age.

Answer (score 0):

You can batch queries like this [check here](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/batching-client-graphql-queries-a685f5bcd41b/) :

[image]

Comment: `getUserAge` needs the user id supplied. How can you pass on the id from the getUsers to the getUserAge?

Comment: you can put the params in variables as shown in image.

Comment: But we don't know the parameters (ie. user id) in advance. The whole point was to combine the two queries into one by "passing down" the id somehow.